# Printing prime number in python

Tags: python, loops, logic

I am trying to print prime numbers in python in the range 3-50. Here is the code:

```
for i in range(3,51):
flag=0
    for j in range(3,i):
        if(i%j==0):
            flag=1
    if(flag==0):
        print(i)
```

The code is running correctly except THAT IT IS ALSO PRINTING 4. Please tell if there is anything wrong with the logic of the code (ignore the efficiency issues).

Comment: For `i=4` you run `j` in the range `(2,2)`, which is an empty range. If you increase the endpoint by one, you will find a factor.

Comment: as @khelwood suggested, change the line `for j in range(2,int(i/2))` to `for j in range(2,int(i/2)+1)` It should work

Comment: please check the edited version it is still giving me 4 as output

Comment: I said increase the endpoint. I didn't say increase the startpoint. If you start your range at 3, you're still missing out 2.

Comment: what is wrong if i start j from 3? please refer to the edited version of code the previous was posted by mistake...

Comment: "what is wrong if i start j from 3?" — 2 is the factor you are looking for. If you start j at 3, obviously you're not going to find 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `range(3,i)` to `range(2,i)` because if we use `range(3,i)`, 4 is not checked with division by 2. As a result 4 is returned as prime.

```
for i in range(3,51):
    flag=0
    for j in range(2,i):
        if(i%j==0):
            flag=1
    if(flag==0):
        print(i)
```

However, a more structural and efficient way is to use the following:-

```
def isPrime(num):
    for i in range(2,num/2+1):
        if (num%i==0):
            return False
    return True

for i in range(3,51):
    if isPrime(i):
        print i
```

We don't need to check the division by all numbers till the number itself for prime. Because if we can check till  the half of the given number only for increased efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

```
print(2)
for i in range(3,51):
    flag=0
    for j in range(2,int(i/2)):
        if(i%j==0):
            flag=1
    if(flag==0):
    print(i)
```

When i = 4, the range will be range(2,2) which is 0. It will not enter the if(i%j == 0): block. Thus your flag would always be 0 when i = 4.

One way to solve it would be to just add a check if i is 4.

```
if(flag==0 and i != 4):
```

Edit : As commented by others, by incrementing the range by 1 would be a better fix than checking if the value is 4.

```
for j in range(2,int(i/2)+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
start = 3
end = 50

for val in range(start, end + 1): 

# If num is divisible by any number   
# between 2 and val, it is not prime  
if val > 1: 
   for n in range(2, val): 
       if (val % n) == 0: 
           break
   else: 
       print(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = int(input("enter smaller no."))
b = int(input("enter larger no."))
for i in range (a,b+1):
    if  i>1:
        for c in range(2,i):
            if i%c == 0:
                break
        else:
            print(i)
```

In the code above we ran a for loop from minimum to the maximum number and storing the value in i

```
for i in range (a,b+1):
```

then we check that the number stored in i is greater than 1 or not as all numbers are divisible by 1 and we don not want to consider it.

```
 if  i>1:
```

after this we run another loop, this time from 2 to 1 less  then the number stored in i

```
for c in range(2,i):
```

Now we check that the number stored in i is divisible by any of the number from 2 to 1 number less then itself.

```
if i%c == 0:
```

If yes then clearly it is not a prime number and we break the loop.

```
break
```

And if no we print the number.

```
else:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(3,51):
    flag=0
    for j in range(2,i):
        if(i%j==0):
            flag=1
    if(flag==0):
        print(i)
```

This prints
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47

4%2 = 0

4%3 = 1

So if you start from 3 you will miss out that 4%2 is = 0

Comment: can you tell me what difference did it make in changing range to (2,i)?

Comment: Because you want to have 2 in your i%j equation.
4%2 = 0
4%3 = 1

Answer (score 0):

For 4 it probably does not go inside the if loop. So I increased the range for i.

```
print(2)
for i in range(3,51):
    flag=0
    for j in range(2,int(i/2)+1):
        if(i%j==0):
            flag=1
    if(flag==0):
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list would have bigger numbers, you should change

```
range(2,int(i/2)+1)
```

for

```
range(2,math.floor(math.sqrt(n)+1))
```

For instance, 400 will try numbers until 20 instead of 200.

Answer (score 0):

try`for j in range(2,i):`the numbers 4 is divisible is 1,2,4 if you start from 3 and continue until 4 but not four you can't find any divisors that is why it is considering 4 as a prime

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
for num in range(1,50):
if num>1:
    if num==2:
        print(num)
    elif num%2==0:
        continue
    else:
        for i in range(3,math.ceil(math.sqrt(num)),2):
            if num%i==0:
                break
        else:
            print(num)
```

It is more efficient as it avoids even numbers and also check for the odd divisors up-to square root of the number which is more efficient than checking up-to only half of the given numbers